# Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1

Tags: iphone, xcode

my Xcode make a problem if I try to run my code on my phone.

```
CodeSign /Users/fboulegue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Optibelt-Scanner-emdojrjggsstlofztblkozlwqznq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Optibelt-Scanner.app
    cd /Users/fboulegue/Desktop/Optibelt-Scanner
    setenv CODESIGN_ALLOCATE /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
    setenv PATH "/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
    /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "iPhone Developer: fabian boulegue (7U338PL287)" --resource-rules=/Users/fboulegue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Optibelt-Scanner-emdojrjggsstlofztblkozlwqznq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Optibelt-Scanner.app/ResourceRules.plist --entitlements /Users/fboulegue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Optibelt-Scanner-emdojrjggsstlofztblkozlwqznq/Build/Intermediates/Optibelt-Scanner.build/Debug-iphoneos/Optibelt-Scanner.build/Optibelt-Scanner.xcent /Users/fboulegue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Optibelt-Scanner-emdojrjggsstlofztblkozlwqznq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Optibelt-Scanner.app

/Users/fboulegue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Optibelt-Scanner-emdojrjggsstlofztblkozlwqznq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Optibelt-Scanner.app: replacing invalid existing signature
/Users/fboulegue/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Optibelt-Scanner-emdojrjggsstlofztblkozlwqznq/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Optibelt-Scanner.app: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED
Command /usr/bin/codesign failed with exit code 1
```

anyone have ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably you didn't install the right certificate on keychain, or you haven't added the device to the provisioning profile.

Here's a nice link that should help you (has a list of possible issues causing your problem): http://esscomp.co.uk/?tag=cssmerr_tp_not_trusted

Search for `cssmerr_tp_not_trusted` on google and there's more.

**EDIT:**

Make sure you installed Apple WWDR certificate (you can download it from Apple Developer Portal, 'Certificates' section `*If you do not have the WWDR intermediate certificate installed, click here to download now.`). Make sure it doesn't also show up in keychain more than once.
[image]

After you install/reinstall WWDR certificate check if your certificate still shows `This certificate was signed by an unknown authority`. If it doesn't try to build.

If you still have issues you'll most probably need to recreate the certificate, see `Certificates/How To` section from the provisioning portal for a nice tutorial on how to do this.

You should delete all your invalid certificates to prevent any conflict.

Comment: Well i fond some problem ... i think that it but no idea how to fix it

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/659484/1.png
http://dl.dropbox.com/u/659484/2.png